# How to use the same field as foreign key for different tables?

Tags: sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a number of tables that will work as source data, one per scientific area (BioData, GeolData, GravData, MagnData, and so on).
There is another table, the main one, named Product that store the info of each product like its id, the project associated, etc. Each product is also composed by a set of data. This data records are stored in those disciplinar tables.

To store the relation between a product and data records of BioData for example, what i've done was to create a many-to-many table named Dataset_Data. This declaratives were generated using sqlacodegen that is an 'Automatic model code generator for SQLAlchemy'.

```
t_Dataset_Data = Table(
    'Dataset_Data', metadata,
    Column('dataset_id', ForeignKey(u'Product.product_id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('data_id', ForeignKey(u'BioData.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    schema='public'
)

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Product'
    __table_args__ = {u'schema': 'public'}

    project_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'Projects.p_id'), nullable=False)
    dataTable_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'DataTables.id'), nullable=False)
    product_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    project = relationship(u'Projects')
    datatablename = relationship(u'DataTables')

    data = relationship(u'BioData', secondary=t_Dataset_Data)
```

Using sqlAlchemy, when I access to a certain Product object, with prod.data I will have access to all BioData records that are associated with my product. 
So far so good.

What I need now is to allow the relation of Product with all the other data tables, ie, instead of using BioData, use another data table like GeolData for example. Note that one product is always related with just one disciplinar table, ie, the data records that make the product come from the same data table according to the dataTable_id of the product.
So what I need is to declare on t_Dataset_Data that the foreign key could be another table (and not only Biodata) and consequently the 'data' attribute of Product could be another source.

In short, I need to know if is possible to use different FK's in the column 'data_id' of Dataset_Data, ie, how could I point to different tables using this column.
If not possible, which could be the best approach to achieve what I need?

Comment: Awful that this hasn't been answered yet. I'm trying to do something very similar right now, and it's a real headache :)

Will update if I manage to get it working